# What is the difference between the Dell 1907FPf and 1907FPc monitors?

Tags: display

They look the same, but I'm worried the circuits won't be. Basically I have broken 1907FPf and I need to replace the power inverter board. I have found a broken 1907FPc for sale, and I'm wondering if I can swap out the board from this. I've tried searching for the differences but can't find much on them.

I think the answer needs to come from someone who has taken both monitors apart at some point.

Comment: Looks like 1907FP is the product *name* and 1907FPc/1907FPf are the product *model numbers*.

Comment: I was under the impression that even the Japanese abandoned that practice.

Comment: @ldigas The ancient art of inverter board replacing...?

Comment: The practice of naming models 434445FpXssX :-)

Comment: Haha, well it is a 4 year old monitor, so maybe they have.

Comment: China is worse... CN-01234-0123456789-0123 (for some CRT monitors we have over here), where the first sequence of numbers (A) is the model number, the middle sequence (B) is ???, and the last sequence (C) seems to be the serial number. However, I have seen monitors being of two different models with the same sequence A and only two numbers were different in sequence B... So much for model numbers. They should go with codenames. "My screen is a *CompanyX* *Flamer* *B*!" Even though *Flamer* might not be the best name for a monitor, for rather obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought the monitor anyway, and thought it'd be considerate to post the difference here. They are in fact *very* different inside, but exactly the same on the outside.

#### 1970FPf (power board only)

It does of course come with a video board, but it's buried under a half dismantled monitor right now, so here's the power board (the bit I wanted to swap out).

[image]

#### 1970FPc (power board and video board)

I was hoping that at least the transformer (yellow) would be the same, but no.

[image]